# How to make QTabWidget display icon for current tab on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have a problem using 
`QTabWidget::setTabIcon()` on Mac. The icon is displayed only when the tab is not current. Once the tab with icon becomes current, the icon is replaced with empty space.

Is this a bug? OS limitation? Is there any fix?

Comment: Without seeing any code where you are actually using the function it is kind of hard to spot the error ;)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Do you have any custom style sheets on the QTabWidget?

Comment: The code is just a call to ``setTabIcon()``. The icon is valid: it is displayed as soon as I switch to another tab and disappear when I switch back.

No, I don't use any style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in QMacStyle::drawControl method there is no code for drawing of icon element:

```
p->save();
rotateTabPainter(p, myTab.shape, myTab.rect);

QPalette np = tab->palette;
np.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(0, 0, 0, 75));
QRect nr = subElementRect(SE_TabBarTabText, opt, w);
nr.moveTop(-1);
int alignment = Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::TextShowMnemonic | Qt::TextHideMnemonic;
proxy()->drawItemText(p, nr, alignment, np, tab->state & State_Enabled,
                           tab->text, QPalette::WindowText);

np.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(255, 255, 255, 255));
nr.moveTop(-2);
proxy()->drawItemText(p, nr, alignment, np, tab->state & State_Enabled,
                           tab->text, QPalette::WindowText);
p->restore();
```

In my case, as fast solution, I patched this problem by adding the following code before previous one:

```
QString oldText = myTab.text;
myTab.text = "";
QCommonStyle::drawControl(ce, &myTab, p, w);
myTab.text = oldText;
```